# How do I generate a correlogram from a GeoTiff using R?

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, autocorrelation

I'm trying to evaluate the scale of spatial autocorrelation for a bunch of rasters I have as GeoTIFFs.  I'd like to be able to do this entirely using R, in order to maintain smooth workflow.

What's the best way of going from GeoTIFF to correlogram using R?

Answer (score 2):

It would be good if you provided a bit more detail to your question and indicated what you have already tried. Working examples are always appreciated.

Here is a function that calculates a correlogram on point data. You could, in theory, modify it to operate on a raster or on a subsample of a raster. Although, I wonder about the computational tractability of calculating a correct correlogram on a raster. For computational reference, see how long it takes to run on the n=155 in meuse with only 99 Monte Carlo simulations. You may want to give some thought as to exactly what you are after and how to approach the problem.

This code implements a correlation approach and not Moran's. You could easily modify the code to return a Moran's correlogram by creating a spatial weights matrix and then calling the "moran" function in spdep. Please run through the example in the header. If you end up using this code in an analysis or publication, please credit me.

```
######################################################################################
# PROGRAM: correlogram.R
# USE: CREATES A CORRELOGRAM 
# REQUIRES: sp, ggplot2 
#               
# ARGUMENTS:  
#      x         SpatialPointsDataFrame OBJECT
#      v         TEST VARIABLE IN x
#      dist      DISTANCE LAG. IF latlong=TRUE DISTANCE UNITS ARE KM
#      latlong   IS IN latlong COORDINATE SPACE (TRUE/FALSE)
#      dmatrix   SHOULD A DISTANCE MATRIX BE RETURNED (TRUE/FALSE)
#      ns        NUMBER OF SIMULATIONS TO DERIVE SIMULATION ENVELOPE
#      ...       ARGUMENT TO BE PASSED TO cor ("pearson", "kendall" or "spearman")
# 
# VALUE:  
#    A LIST OBJECT CONTANING
#      Autocorrelation   A data.frame OBJECT CONTANING 
#                           autocorrelation  AUTOCORRELATION VALUE FOR EACH DISTANCE LAG 
#                           dist             DISTANCE LAGS
#                           lci              LOWER CONFIDENCE INTERVAL (p=0.025)   
#                           uci              UPPER CONFIDENCE INTERVAL (p=0.975)
#      CorrPlot        A ggplot2 OBJECT OF THE CORRELOGRAM
#      dmatrix         DISTANCE MATRIX (IF dmatrix=TRUE)
#                                                                       
# EXAMPLES:
#    require(sp)
#    require(ggplot2)   
#      data(meuse)
#        coordinates(meuse) = ~x+y
#          d=50
#    zinc.cg <- correlogram(x=meuse, v=meuse@data[,"zinc"], dist=d, ns=99)
#      zinc.cg$CorrPlot
#      
# CONTACT: 
#     Jeffrey S. Evans 
#     Senior Landscape Ecologist 
#     The Nature Conservancy,
#     Development by Design
#     Affiliate Assistant Professor
#     University of Wyoming,
#     Zoology & Physiology 
#     Laramie, WY
#     (970)672-6766
#     jeffrey_evans@tnc.org
######################################################################################
correlogram <- function(x, v, dist=5000, latlong=FALSE, dmatrix=FALSE, ns=999, ...){
 if (!require(sp)) stop("sp PACKAGE MISSING")
   if (!require(ggplot2)) stop("sp PACKAGE MISSING") 
     if ( (inherits(x, "SpatialPointsDataFrame")) == FALSE) 
        stop("MUST BE SP SpatialPointsDataFrame OBJECT")
    options(warn=-1)
    options(scipen=999) 
    distmatrix <- function (x, y=x, longlat=FALSE) {
      if (is(x, "Spatial")) {
          stopifnot(identical(proj4string(x), proj4string(y)))
          if (missing(longlat)) 
              longlat = !is.na(is.projected(x)) && !is.projected(x)
          x = coordinates(x)
          y = coordinates(y)
      }
      stopifnot(ncol(x) == ncol(y))
      if (ncol(x) != 2) {
          if (longlat) 
              stop("cannot compute spherical distances for LongLat")
          d = outer(x[, 1], y[, 1], "-")^2
          if (ncol(x) > 2) 
            for (i in 2:ncol(x)) d = d + outer(x[, i], y[, i], "-")^2
          matrix(sqrt(d), nrow(x), nrow(y))
      }
      else {
          spDiN1 = function(x, y, ll) spDistsN1(y, x, ll)
          if (nrow(x) < nrow(y)) 
              matrix(t(apply(x, 1, spDiN1, y = y, ll = longlat)), 
                nrow(x), nrow(y))
          else matrix(apply(y, 1, spDiN1, y = x, ll = longlat), 
              nrow(x), nrow(y))
        }
    }
    w <- distmatrix(coordinates(x)) 
      aa <- ceiling(max(w) / dist)
      bw <- seq(0, aa * dist, dist)
    cors <- NULL
      for(i in 1:aa){
        w1 <- ifelse(w > bw[i] & w <= bw[i+1], 1, 0)
          w2 <- w1
          for(j in 1:dim(w1)[1]){
            nu <- sum(w1[j,])
            if(nu>0){
              w2[j,] <- w1[j,]/nu
            } 
          }
        lag <- w2 %*% v
       cors <- c(cors, cor(v, lag, ...))
      }
    if ( length(which(is.na(cors)) ) > 0) {
      print ( paste(length(which(is.na(cors))), "LAGS EMPTY AND DROPPED", sep=" ") )
      bw <- bw[-which(is.na(cors))]
      cors <- cors[-which(is.na(cors))]
    }
    mc <- matrix(NA, nrow=ns, ncol=length(cors))
        for(s in 1:ns){
          x@data$rand <- sample(x@data$zinc, dim(x)[1], replace=F)
            rcors <- NULL
            for(i in 1:aa){
              w1 <- ifelse(w > bw[i] & w <= bw[i+1], 1, 0)
                w2 <- w1
               for(j in 1:dim(w1)[1]){
                  nu <- sum(w1[j,])
                  if(nu > 0){
                    w2[j,] <- w1[j,]/nu
                  } 
                }
              lag <- w2 %*% x@data$rand
             rcors <- c(rcors, cor(x@data$rand, lag))
            }
         mc[s,] <- rcors
    }
    bw <- bw[-1]    
    cg <- data.frame(cbind(cors, bw ) )
      cg <- cbind(cg, t(apply(mc, 2, quantile, probs=c(0.025, 0.975)))) 
        names(cg) <- c("autocorrelation", "dist", "lci", "uci")
    gg <- ggplot(cg, aes(dist, autocorrelation)) + geom_point(colour = "darkblue", size=3) +
       geom_line(colour = "red") + scale_x_continuous("Distance(M)", 
        limits=c(min(cg$dist), max(cg$dist))) + scale_y_continuous('Autocorrelation',
         limits=c(-1,1)) + theme_bw() + geom_hline(yintercept=0) + 
          geom_smooth(aes(ymin=lci, ymax=uci), 
           stat="identity", fill="blue", colour="darkblue")        
  if (dmatrix == TRUE ) {
    return( list(Autocorrelation=cg, CorrPlot=gg, dmatrix=w) ) 
   } else {  
    return( list(Autocorrelation=cg, CorrPlot=gg) ) 
  }
}
```

Comment: For projected rasters of any appreciable size, it will be *far* more efficient to compute the correlogram using the Fast Fourier Transform.

Comment: I was eventually able to turn up this page, which suggests a number of packages that can be used to generate correlograms from point data: http://www.petrkeil.com/?p=1050

Comment: @whuber Do you have any guidance on computing correlograms for large rasters with FFT, ideally in R?